# Synchronised Buck converter - Soft-Switching

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I have a question regarding the synchronised buck converter. This topology is using two transistors instead of a transistor and a rectifier diode. The bottom switch is used to reduce conduction losses in high power applications. My question: Can this technology be defined as soft switching? The reason why I am asking is that a paper from [Microchip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01471A.pdf) states on page 4 (see below) that this is indeed soft switching. However, I cannot find any other references approving this. In my opinion, Microchip is correct.

*

> *Since the source of the low-side device is tied to ground, the phase
> node must go below ground by a voltage equal to the forward drop of
> the body diode, in order to conduct. Therefore, when the low-side
> switch is turned on, there is only a voltage equal to the forward drop
> of the body diode across it. This leads to a “soft” switching event,
> with losses that are considered negligible in this application note.*

- 

Comment: When the top switch turns off, current starts freewheeling trough the body diode of the lower switch. (because due to required dead time, the low switch can't turn in immediately). When the low switch turns on a bit later it only has to take over from the already conducting body diode. I guess you could call that "soft-switching".

Comment: It simply means that you have a zero-voltage switching (ZVS) condition in the low-side switch: since the body diode of the controlled switch will always spontaneously turn on when the upper-side switch turns off, the synchronous MOSFET is activated with a diode forward drop only across is drain-source terminals hence the *soft-switching* event, naturally minimizing the turn-on losses. However, the body diode is turned-off in the hard way.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answers my question.